# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in what is ment buy it beind an object?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been on the site for some time now and I can't seem to get the idea that most of the similar questions are getting answers for this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Saying it is an object. I am fairly new to PHP and it would really help if anyone could explain this to me. I am trying to retrieve data from my database and echo it in a table.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","technoage");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = 1,$dbcon");
if(!$results)
{
    die("Database query failed".mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo $row['descreption']." ".$row['price']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: DON'T MIX MYSQL and MYSQLI - This isn't pick-and-mix

Comment: you are mixing mysqli with mysql

Answer (score 5):

You are connected with `mysqli`

but your are querying with `mysql`

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM.....
```

Comment: Yeah... this solved the problem. ;) Don't know why the question is negative?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your code with mysqli not mysql as you are mixing mysqli with mysql.

this

```
   $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = 1,$dbcon");
```

should be

```
   $results = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = 1");
```

and this

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
```

should be

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is not caused by mixing mysql and mysqli. It's caused by inserting `$dbcon` into your SQL string itself, here:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = 1,$dbcon");
                                                           // ^ here
```

The connection should be passed as the **first** argument with the query as the **second**. You're inserting it into the SQL string and passing it as a single argument, which means PHP tries to convert the object to a string.

Change to:

```
$results = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = 1");
```

As others point out, you need to change all `mysql_` references to `mysqli_` but this is your secondary problem. The immediate problem is the string issue and once that's fixed, you will encounter the mixing mysql problem.